# Forbid token to parse extra whitespace

Tags: pharo, petitparser

Now idea is like this: in Java for `octalIntegerLiteral` I have a rule

```
octalNumeral, (integerTypeSuffix optional)
```

But I want to get a numbers as token, so I used:

```
octalNumeral javaToken, (integerTypeSuffix optional)
```

The problem is that it starts to parse strings like: `0777 L`. Can this be easily solved, or I should just deal with it is subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that `#javaToken` does two things at once: trimming whitespace and creating tokens. Split this behavior into two separate parsers that you can use individually. To keep old code working you can then redefine `#javaToken` from the new basic parsers as:

```
PPParser>>#javaToken
    ^ self javaPlainToken javaWhitespace
```

Then your number parser would look like this:

```
(octalNumber javaPlainToken , integerTypeSuffix optional) javaWhitespace
```